# Difference in Difference singularities

Tags: difference-in-difference

I need to estimate a difference-in-difference regression to understand the effect of a policy on various municipalities. I have a dataset that spans from 2001 to 2019, covering almost 7,900 municipalities. I am using R for the analysis.

I have a column indicating the precise year of policy implementation for each municipality, and this variable is called "Time." The dependent variable I want to test is called "INCOME_GR," which represents the annual income growth of residents in the municipality.

The policy I want to test was not applied uniformly across all territories. The application of this policy can vary in different percentages for each territory, making it dynamic. The variable "Perc_Policy" indicates the frequency of policy application in each territory, which serves as the "treatment." This value ranges from 0 to 1, where 1 indicates that the entire territory is subject to the policy, while lower frequencies indicate smaller portions of the territory affected. For example, a value of 0.35 indicates that 35% of the municipal territory is subject to the policy. A value of 0 means there is no treatment.

The year of policy implementation can also vary because not all municipalities implemented it in the same year, making it "staggered."

The "treated" group in the first tested year of the policy consists of 420 municipalities. In the last tested year, the treated group comprises 1,243 municipalities. I have a minimum of 3 years of pre-treatment estimation and a minimum of 10 years of post-treatment estimation.

When estimating the DID (difference-in-differences) regression:

```r
DID_INC_GR <- plm(formula =INCOME_GR ~ Perc_Policy * TIME, data = My_Data, effect = "twoways", model = "within", weights = WEIGHT)
```

I have highly significant results (***).

The fact that this policy was implemented in different time periods across municipalities, rather than in a common time period for all municipalities, can introduce statistical challenges that hinder the interpretability of the results. To overcome this issue, I applied a methodology called "group-time average treatment effect" using the "did" package.

The "did" estimation allows for the decomposition of the treatment effect over the years, providing a more robust Average Treatment Effect. The results are significant, especially for the early years of intervention.

The problem I encounter is when I attempt to estimate individual years using the within two-ways regression model (for example, estimating for the year 2004 only, with 420 units in the "treated" group).

Twoways effects Within Model

```
Call:
plm(formula = INCOME_GR ~ Perc_Policy * TIME, data = Policy_application_2004, 
    weights = WEIGHT, effect = "twoways", model = "within")

Balanced Panel: n = 5656, T = 19, N = 107464

Residuals:
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.7750 -0.0097 -0.0001  0.0000  0.0089  6.3058 

Coefficients: (1 dropped because of singularities)
                Estimate        Std. Error      t-value     Pr(>|t|)    
Perc_Policy     -1.0055e-02     1.3702e-02      -0.7339     0.463    
TIME            5.1844e-06      1.1225e-06      4.6185      3.87e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    440.1
Residual Sum of Squares: 435.01
R-Squared:      0.00031699
Adj. R-Squared: -0.055418
F-statistic: 12.7934 on 2 and 101788 DF, p-value: 2.7836e-06
```

1. Perc_Policy is no longer significant.
2. Perc_Policy * TIME is dropped due to singularities.

I have also attempted to include some confounders in the regression, but the results remain unchanged. Therefore, I have encountered a singularity problem, and I'm unsure about its cause.
Perc_Policy is totally exogenous and theoretically it has no correlation with INCOME_GR.
I have considered that the issue may arise from the fact that a "treated" group of 420 municipalities is too small for the estimation, but the sample size seems acceptable to me.

Could someone provide possible causes and solutions? Can the instability in the estimates for individual years also affect the rest of the regressions when including all years of policy application (with a larger number of observations for the treated group)?

Comment: Welcome. I suspect the 2004 estimate is the first year when those 420 municipalities were treated, ignoring the years thereafter? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, 2004 is the first year on my dataset for that policy. Actually it started earlier for some municipalities, but since my data starts from the year 2000 I needed some pre-teatment period for the model.
I am now working with the Extended TWFE and the 2 stage DID approach, it seems it is working better, because of the disaggregation of the different years.

Comment: I don’t see any reason why the interaction would be dropped, unless one of the variables wasn’t coded properly. Does `Perc_Policy` vary over time, or once treated does a municipality experiencing the same frequency (dose) in each of the post-policy periods?

Comment: Perc_Policy may increase over time. There is no possibility of decreasing or coming back from that policy. Anyway, increases may be substantial for some units, passing from 0,5% of municipal territory involved to 40%, for example.
Of course data is always extremely important, and I checked it. anyway I wil triple-check it.
Using the ETWFE package, the regression drops specific observations for singularity, while keeps all the rest, confirming extremely significant results. I will check for those specific observations in order to understand if there is any data or coding problem.